# Robobrowser Login: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, web-scraping, robobrowser

I am trying to login to the following website. However, I do struggle as I think I have to click on the "Log In" Button frist to access the form. Can someone help?

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
browser = RoboBrowser()
login_url = 'https://coin.fyi/'
browser.open(login_url)
form = browser.get_form(id='login-form')
form['Username or email'].value = 'myusername'
form['Password'].value = 'mypassword'
browser.submit_form(form)
```

The following error occurs:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-8c90b79a2ae6> in <module>()
----> 1 form['Username or email'].value = "xxx"

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Additionally I get the following warning:

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py:181: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 193 of the file C:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py. To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP})

to this:

 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, "lxml")

  markup_type=markup_type))
```

Cheers

Comment: You can ignore the warning if you like, or fix it as by the suggestion in the error message. However it's not your root-cause. That is simply that the form you expect isn't there, so form is None, leading to follow-up errors.

Comment: Ok, but isn´t that the reason because I did not click the login button? How do I perform that?

Comment: I don't see you click a button before you reference the form. And from the looks of it, you need o fill the form first, don't you? So if there is no form to begin with, you can't possibly do that...

Comment: Yes I think so too, but I do not know how to click the button using RoboBrowser. Any code example?

Comment: That is a different problem. Your problem states that you can't fill a form, because that form is not there. To that I gave a hint. The login-button probably is the button that sends the filled form, so without solving that problem first, how do you expect to continue with that?

Comment: I took a look at the site. You should work on phrasing your problem better, as "pressing the login button" meant after loading the site in the browser. Please provide more context in the future. And regarding your problem: you can't solve it with this approach. It needs javascript to run. So you could try selenium, or you can try & fake the form because in the end what matters is that the proper request hits the server. It then dependes on the page if the results are usable to you, or if there again javascript is needed.

Comment: Sorry and cheers, figured it out using selenium.

Comment: @deets it is a basic html form

Comment: @PaulNicolashunter it is a basic HTML form that appears in the DOM only after you pressed a button, so it involves running JavaScript. How do you do that through BS?

Comment: @deets I was talking about the following error, the  parser one

Comment: @PaulNicolashunter  When you say "html form" you seem talking about the actual problem he had. Not the warning about the unspecified parser that has no actual consequence for the code, even if one *should* fix it.